# Can't see django site being run in docker container on localhost

Tags: django, docker

I have a django app that I will need to deploy on Amazon's EC2 Container Service. In the meantime, in order to test the deployment, I am trying to deploy it in a docker container locally first, but even when running a simple demo django application, I am unable to see the page at localhost:8000.

Here is my setup.

Create a docker machine:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox testmachine
```

After this I set up my environment:

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env testmachine)"
```

I set up a Dockerfile for my test container:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install python-pip -y

RUN pip install django

RUN mkdir django_test

RUN cd django_test && \
    django-admin.py startproject django_test .
```

Then I call

```
$ docker build -t dockertest .
... builds successfully
$ docker run -d -i -t -p 8000:8000 dockertest
cbef144ac068eb61b0c3e032448cc207c8f0384a9a67a710df6d9beb26d2ab32
$ docker attach cbef144ac068eb61b0c3e032448cc207c8f0384a9a67a710df6d9beb26d2ab32

root@cbef144ac068:/# cd django_test
root@cbef144ac068::/django_test# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This successfully starts the server  at 0.0.0.0:8000/ of the container.

However, when I try to go to localhost:8000 in my browser, I get a "This webpage is not available." What am I missing?

Comment: For me, the issue was resolved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849000/connection-refused-by-docker-container

Comment: For me, the issue was resolved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849000/connection-refused-by-docker-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at the wrong IP.

To figure out the correct IP, I ran:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME          ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
testmachine   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

I then loaded 192.168.99.100:8000 in my browser, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: For those who are not using docker-machine, you can use this command to get the real ip of your container `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' CONTAINER_ID`