# Connection refused by Docker container

Tags: django, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've struggled with this for quite some time.

I have a Django application and I'm trying to package it into containers.

The problem is that when I publish to a certain port (8001) the host refuses my connection.

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

When I try to curl or reach by browser 192.168.99.100:8001, the connection is refused.

```
C:\Users\meow>curl 192.168.99.100:8001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 8001: Connection refused
```

First remark: I'm using Docker Toolbox.

Let's start from the docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    build: ./MongoDocker
    image: ockidocky_mongo
  web:
    build: ./DjangoDocker
    image: ockidocky
    #volumes: .:/srv
    ports: 
    - 8001:8000
    links: 
    - db
```

Second remark: This file orginally gave me some trouble about permission building from scratch. To fix this, I built the images separately.

```
docker build -t ockidocky .
docker build -t ockidocky_mongo .
```

Here's the dockerfile for Mongo:

```
# Based on this tutorial. https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/creating-a-mongodb-docker-container-with-an-attached-storage-volume/
# Removed some sudo here and there because they are useless in Docker for Windows

# Set the base image to use to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:latest
# Set the file mantainer
MAINTAINER meow

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver  hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 && \
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org


VOLUME ["/data/db"]
WORKDIR /data

EXPOSE 27017
#Edited with --smallfiles (Check this issue https://github.com/dockerfile/mongodb/issues/9)
CMD ["mongod", "--smallfiles"]
```

Dockerfile for Django is based on [this](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2015/04/19/packaging-django-applications-as-docker-container-images/) other tutorial.

I won't include the code, but it works.

It's important to say that the last row is:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

I changed the docker-entrypoint.sh to run without Gunicorn.

```
echo Start Apache server.
python manage.py runserver
```

At this point `docker ps` tells me that everything is up:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ddfdb20c2d7c        ockidocky             "/docker-entrypoint.s"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:8001->8000/tcp   ockidocky_web_1
2e2c2e7a5563        ockidocky_mongo       "mongod --smallfiles"    2 hours ago         Up 9 minutes        27017/tcp                ockidocky_db_1
```

When I run a docker inspect ockidocky and about ports, it displays:

```
"Ports": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Is this dependant on mounting volumes?

It is one of the things I really can't figure out and gives me a lot of errors with Docker Toolbox.

As far as I can see everything worked fine during the build, and as far as I know the connection that was refused shouldn't depend on that.

EDIT:
After connectinc to the container and listing the processes with `ps -aux`, this is what I see:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.7  3.0 218232 31340 ?        Ssl  20:15   0:01 python manage.p
root         9 13.1  4.9 360788 50132 ?        Sl   20:15   0:26 /usr/bin/python
root        15  0.0  0.2  18024  2596 ?        Ss   20:15   0:00 /bin/bash
root        20  0.1  0.3  18216  3336 ?        Ss   20:17   0:00 /bin/bash
root        33  0.0  0.2  34424  2884 ?        R+   20:18   0:00 ps -aux
```

P.s. Feel free to suggest how I can make this project easier for myself.

Comment: What host / interface is your Django server running on? (needs to be 0.0.0.0, is that default?) I know that it isn't for Flask for example.

Comment: Maybe its because mongo listens to `27017`?

Comment: True, but OP is trying to connect to Django.

Comment: What does `docker logs ockidocky` show? Did you try to connect to the running container and check that Django is actually running?

Comment: Ok. Logs only show this: `$ docker logs ockidocky_web_1 Start Apache server.` I suppose Django has not started. I've also connected to the container and listed processes. I've edited the question for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue. I don't know why I had to specify the door on this line of `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now `docker logs ockidocky_web_1` shows the usual django output messages.

If someone could give a proper explanation, I would be happy to edit and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and additionally, the ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django settings.py, need to include the docker machine IP.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly because of failure on the service you are going to run on your desired port(In your case the desired port is 8001)!

If any networking checks is OK and you don't have any problem with your network, just check your service which going to listen on your desired port! With the high chance of probabilty, your service is not loaded or ran successfully!

The check for your service depends on the service you are running, but sometimes(most of the times) `docker logs YOUR_CONTAINER_ID` could help to know more about your failure reason!